Creating lambda function through CloudFormation by uploading code in s3 bucket
I have uploaded my function code (.zip) to the S3 bucket (in us-east-1 region). I want to launch a lambda function using the CloudFormation template. When I am launching the template from us-east-1 region, I am getting s3:getObject error. The s3 bucket is publicly accessible.
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed. S3 Error Message: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-1'

I am using below below YAML template.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  MediaSuiteRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: "MyCustomRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: mediaconvert.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: translate.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        # AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess
        # AmazonS3FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
        # AmazonTranscribeFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonTranscribeFullAccess
        # AWSElementalMediaConvertFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElementalMediaConvertFullAccess
        # AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        # AWSLambdaRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
        # TranslateFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/TranslateFullAccess

      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CustomPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "iam:PassRole"
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/MediaSuiteRole"

  MyCustomLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Role: !GetAtt MediaSuiteRole.Arn
      Code:
        S3Bucket: lambda-functions-storage
        S3Key: myfirstlambdafunction.zip
      Handler: myfirstlambdafunction.app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.12
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CustomVar1: "52CD6067149FAA49B1698C1025ACC26B"
          CustomVar2: "52CD6067149FAA49B1698C1025ACC26C"


It sounds like you're actually trying to deploy in eu-west-1 (CFN), maybe doublecheck that.

No. I am trying to deploy in us-east-1. https://imgur.com/a/9ecgSzT

Then the bucket is probably located in Ireland (eu-west-1) you can double-check this: aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket lambda-functions-storage

Thanks. There were some issues with the bucket configurations and the above command was showing an Access denied error though my IAM user had S3FullAccess. I've created a new bucket and it's working fine now.

As per CloudFormation AWS Properties Lambda Function Code 
S3Bucket
An Amazon S3 bucket in the same AWS Region as your function. The bucket can be in a different AWS account

Please try with creating new S3 bucket us-east-1 region, update CFN template with new bucket name and deploy.
